# Dynamically replicate buttons in a Relative Layout and Scroll View

Tags: android, xml, button

I want to add buttons dynamically in the similar color pattern as shown in the code snip attached. I have seen various answers however no one satisfies my need. Also want the placing as done for these six buttons. Inshort I want the replication of this xml with new button ids and button text.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="Prospects"
        android:id="@+id/buttonExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3ExploreOne"
        android:background="#22b14c"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="Research"
        android:id="@+id/button2ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4ExploreOne"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4ExploreOne"
        android:background="#6d6e71"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="Connect"
        android:id="@+id/button3ExploreOne"
        android:layout_marginTop="270dp"

        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button6ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button6ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button6ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button6ExploreOne"
        android:background="#e39b35"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="Build"
        android:id="@+id/button4ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button5ExploreOne"
        android:background="#00aeef"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"

        android:id="@+id/button5ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6ExploreOne"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6ExploreOne"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:background="#5865a2"

        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"

        android:id="@+id/button6ExploreOne"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#cd4243"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="    What do want to explore?"
        android:textColor="#00aeef"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2ExploreOne"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2ExploreOne"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a ListView instead?

Comment: No I havent yet .. Tell me more about it !

Comment: ListViews are made for the use case you're describing; scrolling through rows of items with the same layout for each. A tutorial for a ListView is a little out of scope for Stack Overflow, but there are _tons_ of them available through a quick search, and plenty of specialized examples on this site, too.